# How to copy/paste list of commands with chroot

Tags: debian, terminal, chroot

I want to create a script that executes the following commands, one after the other. The problem is the `chroot` command: everything after that command is not copied into the chroot environment as I want it. It is just copied into the normal terminal and executes after I exit from the chroot. Any ideas how to achieve this?

```
mkdir $HOME/live_boot
sudo debootstrap \
    --arch=amd64 \
    --variant=minbase \
    stretch $HOME/live_boot/chroot \
    http://ftp.ch.debian.org/debian/
sudo chroot $HOME/live_boot/chroot
echo "TESTDEBIAN" > /etc/hostname
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xorg \
    linux-image-amd64 live-boot nano vim network-manager
```

Answer (score 1):

chroot accepts passing a command, so I would put the relevant commands into a script an run this script as a chroot argument.